# Amplifier circuit: Voltage divider x KCL

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, kirchhoffs-laws

I was checking the solution to one question when I found out I couldn't use voltage divider rule to easy the formulas, the amplofier circuit (infinite gain):
[image]
My first attempt:
$$ V_{x}=\frac{R_4}{R_1+R_2}.V_{out}$$
$$ V_y=\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_3}.V_x $$
Then, after few manipulations:
$$ V_{out}/V_y =(1+\frac{R_3}{R_2}).(1+\frac{R_1}{R_4})$$

But usising Kirchhoff' current law:
$$\frac{V_{y}}{R_2} = \frac{V_x-V_y}{R_3}= \frac{V_{out}-V_x}{R_1}-\frac{V_x}{R_4}$$

Again, after few manipulations we get:
$$ V_x=R_3.(\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}).V_y \\$$
$$ \frac{V_y}{R_2} = \frac{V_{out}}{R_1}-(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_4}).R_{3}.(\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}).V_y$$
Which reduces to:
$$V_{out}/V_y = \frac{R_1}{R_2} + (1+\frac{R_3}{R_2}).(1+\frac{R_1}{R_4})$$

The latter agrees with the official answer, but why is the first invalid? How did I lost the R1/R2 factor using it?

Comment: I don't understand your very first equation. It seems wrong to me, though there may be some explanation to it that I don't see. R4 is in parallel to R2+R3, when forming a divider with R1 to make Vx. Why isn't that fact showing up in the first equation?

Comment: Yup, now it seems obvious to me as I remove the line connecting to the negative input of the amplifier, it really shows $$(R_2+R_3) || R_4$$Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$ V_x= {{R_4||(R_2+R_3)}\over{R_1+R_4||(R_2+R_3)}}\times V_{out}\$
....**R4 is in parallel with (R2+R3)**. 
The second equation for \$V_y\$ is correct.